# Why form property not displayed on asp.net label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I try to display property of the form on asp.net label.

Here is property:

```
 public string MainTitle { get; set; }
```

Here is label:

```
 <h3><asp:Label ID="lblMainTitle" runat="server" CssClass="text-muted" Text="<%# MainTitle %>"></asp:Label></h3>
```

But in the browser the label is empty. Why MainTitle property not displayed in the label?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint, attaching your debugger and inspecting the value of `MainTitle`?

Comment: can you show where and how you are assigning a value to that property? Or try to edit the get method to return a test string, do you then see that value on the page?

Comment: have you tried <%= MainTitle %> in text. # is for databound i think, and = sign is most useful for displaying single pieces of information

Comment: If that label is not in a Repeater, GridView etc you have to manually call `DataBind()` in `Page_Load`.

Answer (score -3):

Please try as :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMainTitle" runat="server" CssClass="text-muted" Text="<%# MainTitle %>" />
```

Comment: Please explain why changing a tag to a self-closing one would solve this issue.

Comment: Self closing tag will consider text property as value while closing tags will consider value/text as what is written in between tags!